# Node Not Finding Global Module

Tags: node.js, path, node-modules

So I realize that this is a fairly generic title and question, but I've scoured through so many answers, but sadly none of them seem to be working for me. I'm hoping with a little more information from myself perhaps someone has a specific answer, or knows exactly which answer to redirect me to.

My problem: when I install node modules globally (e.g. `npm install -g nightmare`) I'm unable to access them in my project folder. I get the error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nightmare'
...
```

From what I've read so far installing the module locally inside the project folder seems to be the preferred practice (is this true?), but for now during the development phase I'd like to be able to use the modules I have installed globally. I'm newer to node.js so I'm still discovering what the "usual practice" is for these things though. I first installed Node using Homebrew, but being as I had issues with how things were installing and the pathing (which people were saying is common when using Homebrew), I decided to try a clean slate, uninstalling Homebrew, then eventually Node and NPM as well. I reinstalled just Node and NPM via the site, but am still having no luck being able to access my global modules.

I'm pretty confused at this point because I have some node_module files and packages in some random spots, but not where my current global packages are being installed. I'm assuming leftover from a previous installation. That being said I've adjusted my `$NODE_PATH` several times in hopes that I could access the modules, but no such luck with that.

The current installation spot according to a `--verbose` install is `/Users/<user>/.npm-packages/lib`, which I thought was strange being as a lot of the people already answering this question are correcting their paths to things like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` which has things in it for me, but not the modules installed. I'm assuming that (because of the 'local' file it's in) this is the local installing... maybe? To be honest I'm pretty confused at this point as far as why everything is installed where it is and why, even with changing the `$NODE_PATH` I'm unable to access the modules.

If I've missed something or need to include some other output please feel free to ask and prompt for more. I'm not sure what else is needed for more direction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Installing packages locally allows your project to have control over which version your dependency is. The global package might have a different version across environments and can alter the behavior of your project, possibly breaking it.

Comment: Can you share the snippet of your relevant src?

Comment: @peter I can see the definite advantages to installing the packages locally and having them wrapped up in my app. I was just thinking it would be more convenient and lightweight while I was messing around. I think the `link` option might be the way to go for this.
@Xlee can you clarify just a little what you mean by relevant source?

Comment: I find installing packages locally easier during development too. You don't need to bother linking to the global. And if you run into issues where node isn't finding a module, you just need to look in one place: node_modules to see if it's there or not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### You can not import packages that are installed globally.

You have 2 options, either installing locally:

`npm install nightmare --save`

Or creating a local link to the global package:

```
npm install -g nightmare
npm link nightmare
```

Comment: I see! I'm curious as to the purpose of installing the packages globally then. Is it solely for the `link` method? I think that's the route I'll go for now, as it's closer to what I have envisioned for this stage. Thank you for the input!

Comment: The purpose of installing the packages globally is to able to use their executable.
For example after running `npm install -g bower` you can just run `bower COMMAND` in your terminal.

Comment: It really beats the purpose of creating a centralized install of libraries if you had to again install in the local project folder. If the executables can use the centrally installed node modules, then why can't the individual projects do the same?

Comment: I agree, it is a **nightmare** :(

Comment: Agree. While it solves my problem found it's session-effective, meaning if I `link` it in a Windows command window, open up a new VSC won't see it, so have to `link` it inside of this VSC's cmd window.